# Vaadin 7 - Table, how to set right aligment in rows

Tags: java, css, styles, vaadin7

i have problem to set aligment right in rows in table.

I need to keep aligment left in all headers. But i want aligment right only in specific columns. In rows not in headers.

All elements in table are String.

I know there is method:

```
table.setColumnAlignment("Address", Table.Align.RIGHT);
```

But it makes headers and rows aligment right. I need to keep headers aligment left.

```
table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);

table.addContainerProperty("Age", String.class, null);

table.addContainerProperty("Address", String.class, null);
```

I try resolve my problem by css.

```
table.setCellStyleGenerator(new Table.CellStyleGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String getStyle(Table source, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
           return "numeric";
    }
});
```

And my style in CSS is:

```
 .v-table-cell-content-numeric {
        text-align: right;
   }
```

But it dont work.

Any advice?

Regards

Comment: It has been a while, so I do not remember whether the `.v-table-cell-content` is a `div` wrapped in table cell or the cell itself. But if it is a div inside the cell, you need to add probably `width: 100%`, so that the div occupies the whole cell and you actually see the text right aligned. You can inspect this easily with Chrome dev tools.

Comment: It could make sense. Thanks for help. After tests, i will write if it helped. Regards

Comment: In chrome i see style names like:

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yxFe.png


In css i have style:
```
.v-table-cell-content-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
   }
   
   .v-table-cell-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
   }
```

To my style generator i add:

```
    public String getStyle(Table source, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
           return "wrapper";
    }
```

I see bold rows, but still not allign right.

Comment: Yes, it looks to me that you should set the style to `.v-table-cell-wrapper` instead.